# How to attach a gz file to a json object in python?

Tags: python, json, gzip

I have an api that returns a gz file. The application from where I am running the api accepts only json formats. Is there a way to attach the returned gz file to a json object?
Would converting the gz file to base64 format and then creating a json object like
{ "file": "the base64 format" } work?

```
print(json.dumps({'file': base64.b64decode(response_alert.content)}))
```

I get the error

```
Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: Yes.... that would work.  Give it a shot and post your code if you run into trouble!

Comment: I am trying to use base64.b64decode(response.content) to convert the response content which i think is compressed bytes into base64, but i still get an error it is bytes.

Comment: b64decode takes a string and returns it as bytes.... you want the opposite.

Comment: codecs.decode(response_alert.content) tried this but get 'utf-8' codec cant decode byte 0x8b in position1:invalid start byte..have to look for the right decoder maybe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String encoding is `str`→`bytes` and decoding is `bytes`→`str`.  Base64 is the reverse, as it encodes binary data as characters rather than characters as binary data.  However, since many of its use cases involve ASCII protocols like SMTP, `base64.b64encode` actually requires and **returns** `bytes` (ASCII in the latter case).  You therefore want

```
json.dumps(dict(file=base64.b64encode(response_alert.content).decode()))
```

which takes advantage of the default encoding (UTF-8) supporting ASCII text.  On the other end, you don’t have to bother encoding back to `bytes`, since `str` is accepted by `base64.b64decode`.